# How to perform business logic while using async pipes?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, reactive-programming, behaviorsubject

I have been using async pipes for straight binding like:

component.ts:

```
uiData$ = this.someService.uiData$;
```

HTML:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="uiData$ | async as holdingData">
```

Recently there have been some changes in business logic and I need to perform some checks on the data returned by this pipe. so I thought to do it like this:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="uiData$ | async as holdingData">
            {{ storeHoldingData(holdingData) }}
```

Code behind:

```
storeHoldingData(holdingData: HoldingsData): void {
    this.holdingData = holdingData;
    this.doSomething();
  }
```

This introduced me to change detection related issues, So I am wondering if it's a good route to proceed or I shall just jump back to traditional subscribe on ngOnit() pattern.

I can begin with `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` and then declare BheaviorSubjects to propagate the changes.

The new business logic also makes some hide\show decisions for the Tabs in Tab control on the page.

Is there a better to handle such change while sticking with async pipe?

Comment: Add a pipe() to uiData$ and use operators like map to transform the data as you need. You can then continue using the async pipe. Also you should avoid executing functions in template code as it will execute way too often. If you need to perform side effects like storing values on holdingData you can use operators like tap.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I think tap is a good idea to create a local copy of the data, but then how\when to create an Action stream, I think aysn pipe impose OnPush strategy hence I would still need to figure out a way to propagate the changes to UI.

Comment: Why cannot you directly display the streamed output of uiData$ with any modifications you need to make using operators? Why does it need to be stored on another variable? The transform/computation can happen in RxJS operators possibly.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky : uiData$ is one sample, it combines the data with other streams to performs this logic, hence IMO it needs it's own space to do such calculations,  Also some UI controls need to show \hide based upon not so straight forward operators.

Comment: Well there are many ways to approach this but you can absolutely just subscribe and manipulate the stored data. That being said this is why services are made with mechanisms such as RxJS Subject that emits updated data based on actions/interactions. You could also consider stores such as ngrx or similar.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Agree with you, my challenge is to deal with things like: looping over list of currencies and conversion to rate to match with user default currency, this is definitely custom logic which needs a method call to perform and return calculated values which will be displayed on UI, hence the struggle.

Comment: You would probably need to share that logic that is causing the struggle. Without knowing that logic and the specific issues, only generic solutions can be provided.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments: this is a bad practice. Functions called inside of templates get hammered and are performance nightmares.

That said, you should *always* strive for `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`, and the `async` pipe is your friend in this quest.

As for what you should do instead? That really depends on what is happening in the `doSomething()` method. Using the `tap` operator is definitely an option and is specifically for side effects. Another option is put `shareReplay(1)` at the end of that observable stream. T

```
uiData$ = this.someService.uiData$.pipe(shareReplay(1))
```

From there, just re-use the same observable wherever else you need it and it won't make another service call. You could even call subscribe to it in `ngOnInit`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `tap` operator if you want to perform any checks or use data returned from the observable to perform some side effects.

```
uiData$ = this.someService.uiData$.pipe(
             tap(res => this.doSomething(res))
         )
```

As mentioned in the comments above try not calling methods within the templates as it is considered bad practice.